# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:68)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

**Hello everyone. Can someone help me ? I just create react app then i start it immediately. Then i got error something like this. I dont know what's the problem**

Failed to compile.
./src/index.js 1:68
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:68)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/user/OneDrive - Ministere de l'Enseignement Superieur et de la Recherche Scientifique/Bureau/fitland-official/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
> | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
> |

Comment: It means that at line 68 of your index file you have some import that's not digested by webpack. Can you provide a snippet?